# Cant use function to a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a task to check if page is in English, and the following code is not compiling because it writes:

> expected string or bytes-like object

```
train = pd.read_csv('UDSclub/wikipedia_train.csv')

def get_language(page):
    res = re.search('[a-z][a-z].wikipedia.org', page)
    if res:
        return res.group(0)[0:2]
    return 'na'

train['language'].apply(get_language)
```

I am trying to create new column in `DataFrame` where it will be marked if page is in English of not

Comment: It would help if you provided your CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
train = pd.read_csv('UDSclub/wikipedia_train.csv')

def get_language(x):
    res = re.search('[a-z][a-z].wikipedia.org', x['page'])
    if res:
        language = res.group(0)[0:2]
    language = 'na'
    x['language'] = language
    return x

train.apply(get_language)
```

Comment: still exceptions